# Add windows 8 contacts to outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, windows-8

Outlook 2013 (RTM) only shows the contacts synced with my mail accounts, and more specifically those using active sync which basically limits it to outlook.com.

Windows 8 added the contacts hub which has the ability to merge contacts from different platforms but I do not see any way to merge, add or sync those to outlook 2013's address book which is a pity and kind of frustrating.

does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks for your ideas and suggestions.

P.S. using the "contacts" folder makes the contacts unavailable to the people app so that isn't a solution either.

Comment: I don't believe its possible. If there is a way to export the contact information within Windows 8, it would make sense, that Outlook could then import that information.  Considering neither program has actually be released to retail, it will awhile, before anyone really can answer this question.

Comment: @Ramhound It is not possible to export from the metro app (yet). It simply downloads the info from all social networks. You cannot even delete a contact manually from the app, you need to go trough the social network to do so. So no, no way of "managing" your contacts effectively. it is sad really :(

Comment: This means you answered your own question.  It should be noted that Office 2013 has not actually been released to retail yet.  Outlook 2013 certainly has not, I don't think the release date for another month, I could be wrong.  The Office installed on Windows RT tablets does not include Outlook 2013.

Comment: yes but hey it doesn't hurt to ask, maybe someone figured something out within outlook itself :). Release is scheduled for Q1 2013 FYI